# javax.servlet.ServletException: Error creating bean - Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException

Tags: java, hibernate, firebird

Why do I encounter an `javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Error creating bean` on my Java/Hibernate application hosted on an Apache server?

I always fix it by just restarting the whole site. Any suggestions?

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:122)
    com.dpp.web.platform.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:210)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:122)
    com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:108)
    com.dpp.web.platform.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:210)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:325)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:188)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:116)
    com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:108)
    com.dpp.web.platform.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:210)
```

Comment: Did you really mean "beam"; or was it *bean*?

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace, this stacktrace doesn't appear to be complete (it is missing the stacktraces of the exception cause chain).

Comment: In addition to the full stacktraces (check your logs!), also include your connection config (or code). If you are using anything from the `org.firebirdsql.pool` package, then look at ["Important changes to Datasources" in the Jaybird release notes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/2.2.8/release_notes.html#__RefHeading__2753_1560579136). I'd strongly suggest to switch to the equivalent classes in `org.firebirdsql.ds` (if used in JavaEE), or switch to a third party connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that you are you using not good connection pool.
When connection is lost, your connection pool didn't try to establish it back.

Make sure, that your database is always available.